# Atleast one :-capital letter,special character,digit starts with character ,length<8.if 2 conditions fail, display both the messages at once

Tags: python

When I enter the password which contains only number and capital letter program ask to print again in error message.

**Output:**

> Make sure your password has a number and special character in it

**Code:**

```
import re

def validate():
    while True:
        password = input("Enter a password: ")
        if len(password) < 8:
            print("Make sure your password is at lest 8 letters")
        elif re.search('[0-9]' and '[A-Z]',password) is None:
            print("Make sure your password has a number and capital letter in it")            
        elif re.search('[0-9]' and '^[A-Za-z]',password) is None:
            print("Make sure your password has a number and start with character")
        elif re.search('[0-9]' and '[!@#$%^&*:;?,]',password) is None:
            print("Make sure your password has a number and special character in it")
        elif re.search('[A-Z]' and '[!@#$%^&*:;?,]',password) is None:
            print("Make sure your password has a capital letter and special character in it")
        elif re.search('^[A-Za-z]' and '[!@#$%^&*:;?,]',password) is None:
            print("Make sure your password start with character and special character in it")
        elif re.search('[0-9]',password) is None:
            print("Make sure your password has a number in it")
        elif re.search('[A-Z]',password) is None:
            print("Make sure your password has a capital letter in it")
        elif re.search('^[A-Za-z]',password) is None: 
            print("Make sure your password start with character")
        elif re.search('[!@#$%^&*:;?,]',password) is None: 
            print("Make sure your password has a special character in it")
        else:
            print("Your password seems fine")
            break

validate()
```

**Expected output:**

```
Enter the password:12345ASD
Make sure password should start with character and have special character

Enter the password:A1234aaaa
Make sure password have special character in it
```

**Actual output:**

```
Enter the password:12345ASD
Make sure password have number and have start with character

Enter the password:A1234aaaa
Make sure password have number and special character in it
```

Comment: It would probably be better to write one regular expression which will check password string for validity and show to user standard message with requirements to password string in case if password doens't fit them.

Comment: What does this mean: `re.search('[0-9]' and '[A-Z]',password)`? Specifically, what is `'[0-9]' and '[A-Z]'` supposed to mean? It doesn't concatenate the strings or anything like that. You can execute `'[0-9]' and '[A-Z]'` in the interpreter and see what it evaluates to.

Comment: [0-9] is digit and [A-Z] is uppercase letter in output when your giving pasword as asasdfg@s it need to give the ouptut as "Make sure your password has a number and capital letter in it"

Comment: No, that doesn't work like that, reread what ForceBru wrote or just try in an isolated program whether that bit of code works as you think it does. That said, can you extract a [mcve]? Eliminate any manual input and also every conditional that is not relevant. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
import re


def validate():
    while True:
        password = input("Enter a password: ")
        count = 0
        error = []
        if len(password) < 8:
            count += 1
            error.append("is at least 8 letters")
        if re.search('[A-Z]', password) is None:
            count += 1
            error.append("has a capital letter")
        if re.search('[!@#$%^&*:;?,]', password) is None:
            count += 1
            error.append("has a special character")
        if re.search('[0-9]', password) is None:
            count += 1
            error.append("has a digit")
        if re.search('^[A-Za-z]', password) is None:
            count += 1
            error.append("starts with a character")
        if count >= 1:
            print("Make sure your password", error[0], end="")
            if count >= 2:
                print("", "and", error[1])
            else:
                print("")
        if count == 0:
            print("Your password seems fine")
            break


validate()
```

You can change the priority of the errors by switching the if statement blocks according to your need.